# Get download link used for install iOS app store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, analytics

I prepare a contest for my iOS app : 
All the users can invite people for increase his score, 1 installation = 1 point.
For this contest each user have an unique share link.

After the installation, I want to know if the new user has invited.
For that I want to get the installation referer link (like [INSTALL_REFERRER](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver) in android)

I know it's possible with android, but this informations doesn't exist in iOS.
I search an other way without install an analitycs SDK.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm also trying to associate a user with a specific download URL / campaign

Comment: No... In my case, I have a share link, so this link hash/salt the IP and save the hashed IP address, the current date and redirect to the apple store.

When a user open for the first time my app, I call the contest API and search IP occurence... But isn't enough, for exemple if the user download and open the app with an other IP (4G, wifi etc...)

Comment: I was directed to Branch.io from a developer in my network to accomplish this: https://branch.io/?_bt=196737904477&_bk=branch%20io&_bm=e&_bn=g&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIoZ6p4Jq01QIViAFpCh1xxwBAEAAYASAAEgLelPD_BwE

Comment: @DanySousa do you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, sorry ... Take a look to https://branch.io, if you're lucky it can do the job

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you can make use of the Associate Domains option.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html